# Reordering Columns in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular5, ngx-datatable

I had 2 requirements. The first one was to display table with dynamic columns. I was able to implement the requirement. The second one is to allow users to reorder the columns and save it as their preference so that next time they login, they see the columns in the order they saved earlier.

The issue here is, some of my columns have some extra logic on them. Eg: SerialNumber column has a logic that it has to be an anchor tag and clicking the same, will navigate the user to the details of the chosen record. The Status column has a logic to set an icon if the value of it is equal to something.

3 out of 11 columns have such logic where as other 8 are just simple display of values as is.

How do I achieve reordering with the columns that are static (created with ngx-datatable-column) and the ones that are dynamic.

Sample:

```
Dynamic Columns

<ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let col of dynamicColumns" [prop]="col.Name" [minWidth]="130" [sortable]="true ">
  <ng-template let-value="value " let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      <label> {{ row[col.Name] | UTCToLocalTime }} </label>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>

Static Columns:

<ngx-datatable-column prop="TicketNumber" [minWidth]="145" [sortable]="true " [cellClass]="IsSLABreach">
  <ng-template let-value="value " let-row="row " ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      <a (click)="displayTicketDetails(row.TicketId) " class="ticketNumberValue" style="cursor: pointer ">
                    {{ value }}
      </a>
   </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Comment: Any answer for this question...Same requirement i am going to implement.